# Inner loop is repeating too many times while scraping page. About 4-5 times per page

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, beautifulsoup

The inner for loop is repeating multiple times. Therefore I am getting multiple copies of the data when I write it to a csv.

I am using selenium to click through the pages of my search and handing off the page source of each page to BeautifulSoup in order to take the values I need.

I have no issue getting the values, however the output shows repetition of 3-5 times. Therefore I think there is something wrong with my loop.

I have tried using a more focused search of the html using BeautifulSoup in case there are multiple instances of the data in the html, however there is still repetition.

```
count = 1    
while True:
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')        
        leadFields = soup.find_all('div', class_='leadFields')
        snippets = soup.find_all('div', class_="snippet ensnippet")

        for l, s in zip(leadFields, snippets):
            print (l.get_text(strip=True) + s.get_text(strip=True))
            print(count)
            count+=1
        nextBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.nextItem')))
        action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(nextBtn)
        action.click(nextBtn).perform()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

Comment: In this snippet, you are explicitly telling the code to repeat until a timeout exception occurs. You also don't show where `count` is created or used. Is there additional code that needs to be included to make this a [mcve]?

Comment: I edited the code to add count being created. The timeout exception occurs when there is no more pages left to click next page. The inner loop that prints certain text from the page is what is being repeated 3-5 times per page. Timeout then occurs and the outer loop breaks.

Comment: catch the exceptions and check... could be a StaleElement here?  (not familiar with python so not sure what another type of exception would do in your code...)  May also need to use WebDriverWait on that first line (or after the click) to wait for an update to the DOM or a pageload? (check for change of current page nav style or something like that...)

Comment: Thank you for the advice pcalkins it helped out. There is no exceptions to catch because the code did not break. The outer while loop kept running repeatedly during the loading animation produced after the next page button was clicked. To make sure the page load had finished I added a wait until jQuery activity is 0 after the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

After the nextBtn click.

Also if anyone sees this in the future don't use a TimeoutException to break a loop that was temporary.

Shoutouts to pcalkins in the comments for the help.